# Anyone knows why my HTTP post request won't work?

Tags: java, html, post

I am looking for some advice in implementing the following HTML code in Java:

```
<form name="gls" method="post" action="http://datarequester-f01.gls-hungary.com/public/service.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctrcode" value="HU" />
    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="cities" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="getToursDB" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="[{'Lastupdate' : null}]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="plaininput" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="resultformat" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I tried many different approaches, but the response code is always 400.
Here is my last try:

```
String url=""http://datarequester-f01.gls-hungary.com/public/service.php"";
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setHttpProcessor(HttpProcessorBuilder.create().build())
            .build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctrcode", "HU"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("module", "cities"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "getToursDB"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", "[{'Lastupdate' : null}]"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plaininput", "1"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resultformat", ""));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    try {
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(post.getEntity()));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Response Code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GLS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Any adive is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: You should specify what library (and version) you are using. And fix the compile error in the `String url=` line.

Comment: I am using appache httpcore4.4.7 and httpclient 4.5.4. The compile error is also fixed..

Comment: Have you tried to split your problem up? Is it client side or server side? Can you reach your url and get back a 200 from a browser, or does it report 400 as well? Try using [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to snoop your request/response from your client side code if your problem is there. Otherwise figure out your typo on the server side.

Comment: The HTML form works perfectly. The response contains pages of text. I guess that i have this problem because my post messages are different than the html post messages.